# Bootstrap Navbar - Spyscroll Not Working and Other Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, nav

I saw a couple of other questions regarding the spyscroll issue, but they didn't quite apply to my situation. I am trying to apply a simple spyscroll function to the main page of my site and applying it to the nav bar but it doesn't seem to be working.

In addition, I would also like to add a basic scrolling function to these same links..does Bootstrap have a scrolling function? I don't see one listed. What would be the best way to do this?

The site is located at debbierking.com/bootstrap.

Please note that I am new to Bootstrap and my jquery knowledge is minimal...

Relevant markup:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">

  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">

        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">       
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>   
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->

      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->


  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.navbar').scrollspy()
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Am trying to set this up now according to this jsfiddle code from FlabbyRabbit but am still having problems: http://jsfiddle.net/flabbyrabbit/69z7x/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are placing the `navbar` inside your `<head>` which I think doesn't make sense, the example on bootstrap [page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) clearly places the `navbar` inside the `body` tag, also check this [example](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/scrollspy-tutorial.php).

Comment: Actually it isn't...that was my mistake in writing this up here...the navbar is actually inside the header tag in the *body* of the page. My apologies...have just corrected this here.

Comment: I was able to make it work on my machine, just make sure you include jquery before you include bootstrap.
Also you may prefer to put the `data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar"` in the `div` that contains your paragraphs that will be scrolled, just like the bootstrap example.
please update your code to show us where you scroll paragraphs .

Comment: Okay, to make this easier, I am set up the relevant code here: http://jsfiddle.net/DesignLady94/N6UPj/10/ (This is based on the original code from Flabby Rabbit, which works fine (see above comment). I am trying to include both the spyscroll and scrollTo but for some reason can't get it to work. Hopefully this helps...and you will see my scroll divisions there. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, am I supposed to be loading a separate file called bootstrap-scrollspy.js, or is that included in the bootstrap.js file that comes with v.2.2.2?

Comment: you don't have `bootstrap.css` added to your css in the fiddle, and you don't need to include `bootstrap-scrollspy.js` if you are already including the `bootstrap.js`.
I have created a working fiddle for your example, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kabdelhady/vxyWZ/1/

Comment: Thank you Khaled for setting that up! The spyscroll definitely works there...That's what I tried initially but then switched to JS when it didn't work.I noticed that you didn't include any JS for the scrollTo...Am trying to get the two to work together...perhaps they can't?

Comment: Still not working on my site (debbierking.com/bootstrap). The active link keeps switching to About.